# Website Compatible To Other Devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this Website just as a little something to do. I have been trying different methods to get it to be 100% Compatible with all devices, and to fit perfectly in the each device.

I don't know anything about @media queries, nor javascript. So I am quite blank on what option I have.

This is the code I am currently using, but I still need to scroll to right to see the whole page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/script/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
```

I am not really HTML savvy, just mess around with it, and try to create things.

The next solution that I know I could do is just make my images smaller. However by doing this, I obviously won't get the appearance I am particularly after.

Another thing is, how would I get my 'Back To Top' button be in the center of each page, and on all devices?

Javascript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var offset = 220;
            var duration = 500;
            jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                    jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
                } else {
                    jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
                }
            });

            jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Body Code:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

CSS:

```
.back-to-top {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 44%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: transparent;
 background-color: rgba(0, 230, 0, 0.10);
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 1em;
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid #CCFF33;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #00E600;
 color: #C1C1C1;
 outline: none;
 height: 10px;
 width: 180px;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #000, 0 0 0.2em #000, 0 0 0.2em #000;
 text-align: center;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
```

Comment: just a note, Nothing will Ever be 100% compatible with all devices. keep that in mind.

Comment: If I were you, I would follow the "less is more" principle. You can get pretty decent results by using a very simple responsive design, with one, maybe two media queries. In many cases, especially if this is your test site, you can do it without javascript and use % width for images. And you should also keep in mind that not all designs will work well in responsive design. You may need to compromise.

Answer (score 0):

### This is the basics of media queries

You start with designing everything for mobile first in this example and work your way down, changing attributes your each screen size.

```
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

exampleDiv {
 Width:60%;
 height:100px;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
exampleDiv {
 Width:60% height:300px;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
exampleDiv {
 Width:100% height:500px;
}
}
```